MID function won't return 'N/A' as default
I am using a combination of INSTR and MID functions to search a text field for a specific value and if the value is found, I return everything after this text until a period is found.  If the specific value is not found, I want to return "N/A" but instead get a value of #Error. If the value is found, it is correctly displayed but I can't get the 'N/A' to appear; it always returns #Error. I define two fields using INSTR function; one to show the first position that the value is found, and the second to show the position the period is in and use the values in the MID function. I noticed that the INSTR function returns an integer value of 0 if the value isn't found, so I write my MID function to check if the value is 0 and return 'N/A' if it is; i.e,
IIF(Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value=0, "N/A",
    MID(Fields!Comments.Value, 
        Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value, 
        (Fields!Location_of_Period_in_Text.Value - Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value)
       )
    )

.  This works fine if the text value is there but otherwise it shows #Error instead of 'N/A'.

This problem is because both parts of the IIF get evaluated every time, even if the result is never shown.
I can't test this right now but you'll need to test the Starting_Position_of_Text value for each part of the MID(), so something like this..
IIF(Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value=0, "N/A",
    MID(Fields!Comments.Value, 
        IIF(Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value=0, 0, Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value), 
        IIF(Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value=0, 1, (Fields!Location_of_Period_in_Text.Value - Fields!Starting_Position_of_Text.Value))
       )
   )

So, the start position is 0, then we pass 0 and 1 to mid function to get this first character, it doesn't really matter what that is as it will never be shown.
Note: This assumes the Comments field is always at least one character long.

Excellent.  That did it
